# keep an cell value before get updated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image: img]

`D3` is the sum `A` to `C`, which changes often.

How do I keep a value of `D3` every time `F3` is updated?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what causes D3 being updated.

If D3 has a formula that involves the MANUAL entry of cells A3, B3, and/or C3, then you can use a Worksheet_Change Event. It will not monitor the formula in D3, but the data entry values in the three other cells.

If the preceding cells, or D3, are populated by a data feed, then things will get a lot more complicated.

If you don't know what a Worksheet_Change Event is, then please do your homework before posting here.